# Want to display a particular div on checking a checkbox and if it is left unchecked then hide div .Not working IE8/IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have a check box. If i select the check box then i want to display a particular div and if it is left unchecked then hide div . Can someone help me regarding this.  I have done the code for this and working fine in Firefox. But its not working in IE8/IE9. Why? Can someone help . Thanks In advance.

```
<script language="javascript">
function showIPAddress(chkbox) {

    //var chkbox = document.getElementById("chk1");
    if(chkbox.checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
            document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk1" value="1" onClick="showIPAddress(this)" /> <b class="account">Test Checkbox</b>


<div id="div1" name="div1" style = "display:block">
    <b>IP Address: </b><input name="ip"></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I get it work with a simpler code:

```
<script>
  function showIPAddress(chk) {
      document.getElementById("div1").style.display = chk.checked ? "block" : "none";
  }
</script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="1" onClick="showIPAddress(this);" /> <b class="account">Test Checkbox</b>

<div id="div1" style="display:none;">
    <b>IP Address: </b><input name="ip"></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if(chkbox.checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "";
}
else {
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much sure but have you tried this :

```
document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility="visible"/"hidden".
```

Also instead of `onClick` it should be `onclick`.

Comment: yes. but this also not working in IE. I think there is no difference between onClick and onclick.